# Condition merge while merging duplicate of two List

Tags: c#, list, linq, merge

I have two lists,

```
private List<DealResponse> L1 = new List<DealResponse>
{
    new DealResponse {detailId = "5", detailcd = "ABC", fileName = "string 1", isNgo = "0"},
    new DealResponse {detailId = "5", detailcd = "DEF", fileName = "string 2", isNgo = "0"},
    new DealResponse {detailId = "5", detailcd = "XYZ", fileName = "string ", isNgo = "0"}
};

private List<DealResponse> L2 = new List<DealResponse>
{
    new DealResponse {detailId = "5", detailcd = "ABC", fileName = "string 11", isNgo = "1"},
    new DealResponse {detailId = "6", detailcd = "MNO", fileName = "string 3", isNgo = "1"}
};
```

I'm trying to write a method which accepts detailId and return the result by merging above two list, and if there is duplicate (duplicate definition = when detailId, detailcd match between two lists) select entry from L2

so after merging result would be

```
var Result = new List<DealResponse>
{
    new DealResponse {detailId = "5", detailcd = "ABC", fileName = "string 11", isNgo = "1"},
    new DealResponse {detailId = "5", detailcd = "DEF", fileName = "string 2", isNgo = "0"},
    new DealResponse {detailId = "5", detailcd = "XYZ", fileName = "string ", isNgo = "0"},
    new DealResponse {detailId = "6", detailcd = "MNO", fileName = "string 3", isNgo = "1"},
};
```

Note that in result we selected this entry from L2 since detailId = 5, detailcd = ABC was duplicate

```
public List<DealResponse> GetDealResponse(string detailId)   
{
    // My main confusion is while doing union how to handle the case 
    // which I mentioned (On duplicate select entry from second list)  
    var L3 = L1.Union(L2, new DealResponseComprarer()).ToList();         
}  

public class DealResponse
{
    public string detailId { get; set; }
    public string detailcd { get; set; }
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    public string isNgo { get; set; }
}

public class DealResponseComprarer : IEqualityComparer<DealResponse>
{
    public bool Equals(DealResponse x, DealResponse y)
    {
        return x.detailId == y.detailId &&  x.detailcd == y.detailcd ;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DealResponse obj)
    {
        return (obj.detailId.GetHashCode() + obj.detailcd.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: try `var L3 = L2.Union(L1, new DealResponseComprarer()).ToList();`

Comment: @Matt.G In this case how to make sure Im selecting a entry from L2 when there is duplicate.If you look at the results whenever there is a duplicate result should include entry from L2

Comment: I don't understand your `GetDealResponse(int detailId)`. How does `detailId` come into play here? The resulting list shouldn't include elements with `detailId = 6`, just *Distinct* elements with `detailId = 5` (as an example), with a L2 priority.

Comment: It's confusing when you have your method take an `int` for `detailId`, but it's declared as a `string` in the `DealResponse` class.

Comment: @RufusL Sorry that was my mistake, corrected it. Thank you

Comment: @Jimi So all I wanted from this method is accept detail Id as a string (Corrected the method parameter type), and based on the conditions mentioned in question get all the entries which matches passed detailId .

Comment: @Matt.G Thank you, your solution worked for me :)

Comment: Yes, if that's the Class structure, you can get the same results, pass a string value to `GetDealResponse()`. Give me a moment and I'll update the code.

Answer (score 2):

In case you actually want to filter your results using `detailId`, since this value is passed to the `GetDealResponse()` method, you could add a `.Where` condition to the equalized `Union` list.

```
public class DealResponse
{
    public string detailId { get; set; }
    public string detailcd { get; set; }
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    public string isNgo { get; set; }
}

public List<DealResponse> GetDealResponse(string detailId)
{
    return L2.Union(L1, new DealResponseComprarer())
             .Where(elm => elm.detailId.Equals(detailId)).ToList();
}


L1 = new List<DealResponse>() {
new DealResponse() { detailId = "5", detailcd = "ABC" , fileName = "string 1", isNgo = "0" },
new DealResponse() { detailId = "5", detailcd = "DEF" , fileName = "string 2", isNgo = "0" },
new DealResponse() { detailId = "5", detailcd = "XYZ" , fileName = "string ", isNgo = "0" }};

L2 = new List<DealResponse>() {
new DealResponse() { detailId = "5", detailcd = "ABC" , fileName = "string 11", isNgo = "1" },
new DealResponse() { detailId = "6", detailcd = "MNO" , fileName = "string 3", isNgo = "1" }};

string ID = "5";
List<DealResponse> L3 = GetDealResponse(ID);
```

Which would return this list:

```
{ detailId = "5", detailcd = "ABC" , fileName = "string 11", isNgo = "1" }
{ detailId = "5", detailcd = "DEF" , fileName = "string 2", isNgo = "0" }
{ detailId = "5", detailcd = "XYZ" , fileName = "string ", isNgo = "0" }
```

Comment: @Ami  Code modfied. Test it to see if it returns the results you're expecting. (Btw, you have a typo here: `DealResponseComprarer : IEqualityComparer<DealResponse>`).

Comment: your solution solved my problem.Thank you. Also, I tried to up-vote and accept it but it looks like I need minimum 15 reputation to do it  .

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to write a method which accepts detailId and return the result by merging above two list, and if there is duplicate (duplicate definition = when detailId, detailcd match between two lists) select entry from L2

Another way to say this is:

1. Start with L2
2. Add everything from L1 that isn't already in L2

This can be accomplished with one line:

```
var combined = L2.Concat(L1.Except(L2, new DealResponseComprarer()));
```

[Example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UIXm33)